# How to set or change button background color on IBAction

Tags: xcode, button

I try to set the background color of a button, but, isn't work. Some can helpme please?

```
- (IBAction)OrBoton:(id)sender {
     [sender setBackgroundColor:(NSColor *)redColor];     
}
```

But, if I try to setTitle, this works fine. 
Is unacessible the Backgroundcolor property?
I don't recived any error when I Build and Debug, but don't works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally, I opted for change image button from a colored image, because unfortunately, at the moment, this is impossible for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)OrBoton:(id)sender 
{
   UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
   [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: I catch an error : UIButton undeclared and UIColor undeclared

Comment: Did you assign this IBAction to a button using Interface builder or a selector?

Comment: Interface builder. I can get the Tag of the pressed button but I can't put nothing to the button.

Comment: Then why cant you create a object to that button assign the referencing outlet to that button in IB and change any property to that button. Are you assigning the IBAction to many buttons or a single button.

Comment: 25 Buttons... but I think I can get and put any property to the button pressed.. Isn't?

Comment: Weird... Do you still get error or the IBAction doesnt get caled.

Comment: I don't get any error when I build and debug and I can get the Tag of the button pressed because I trap this and put it in a Text for probe. Bud I can't send any to the button, and i don't get any error when I run the application ...

Comment: Well I miss one error, the Title property change, but not the Backcolor property. Is unaccesible this property?

Comment: whats the error it shows? We can set the background color. it is accessible.

Comment: The button type is one possible cause? Is a NSButton Bezel>Bevel, Bordered state Enabled, Continuous and Momentary Push In and Scaling Proportionally Down. I dont think that this is a possible cause but....

Comment: Could I make this with Interface Builder?, because I try to do this in th button Effects, Appeareance, selecting a color but it dont change. There are a red text line that says "Enable CoreAnimation rendering" is this the cause?

Comment: I think that the question is... how make a own button class?

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
- (IBAction)Click:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.selected)
    {
        sender.selected = NO;
        sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = YES;
        sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```